# replacing only numeric values from a column containg alphanumeric, string and numeric values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace the **test_values** with the **desired** values:

```
  test_values desired
0       cat95   cat95
1         123       1
2      dog123  dog123
3        duck    duck
4         456       1
5         666       1
6      bat/23  bat/23
```

any help or reference is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: so `df['test_values']=df['desired']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.loc[df['test_values'].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric()), 'test_values']=df.loc[df['test_values'].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric()), 'desired']
```

Example:

```
  test_values desired
0       cat95     cat
1         123      10
2      dog123     dog
3        duck      du
4         456      15
5         666      20
6      bat/23     bat

df.loc[df['test_values'].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric()), 'test_values']=df.loc[df['test_values'].apply(lambda x: x.isnumeric()), 'desired']

>>>print(df)
  test_values desired
0       cat95     cat
1          10      10
2      dog123     dog
3        duck      du
4          15      15
5          20      20
6      bat/23     bat
```

Answer (score -1):

```
test_data = [ x for x in test_data if not is_instance(x, int) ]
```